# "Format Selection" formats the whole document in VS Code with the Prettier extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, prettier

I am working on a typescript project and i have VS code latest version (Version: 1.68.1 (Universal)).I have prettier installed in VS code and i am having issue when i try to format a selected code. rather than formatting the selection, it format the entire document which makes it hard while code review because of the larger number of git diffs.

I tried editing the settings.json as mentioned in few of the posts but did not help and seems to be deprecated. I also don't see the "Format Selection with" option when in right click in VS code.

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 1):

For a long time, Prettier itself, which the [`esbenp.prettier-vscode`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=esbenp.prettier-vscode) extension for VS Code is built on, has had issues related to range formatting. It's had them in the past (fixed), still has them (not fixed), and more will probably keep being discovered. The maintainers say so themselves [here](https://github.com/prettier/prettier-vscode/issues/2041#issuecomment-886810289). You can find a list by going through https://github.com/prettier/prettier/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+range+.

For examples for issue tickets in the `esbenp.prettier-vscode` extension's repo (which I found just by googling "`site:github.com/prettier/prettier-vscode/issues format selection whole document`"), see [#134](https://github.com/prettier/prettier-vscode/issues/134) (June 2017), [#137](https://github.com/prettier/prettier-vscode/issues/137) (June 2017), [#2041](https://github.com/prettier/prettier-vscode/issues/2041) (June 2021), [#3145](https://github.com/prettier/prettier-vscode/issues/3145) (Sept 2023).

Even historically, there have been releases of `esbenp.prettier-vscode` where certain setups would treat this as a known issue. Ex. [1.18.0](https://github.com/esbenp/prettier-vscode/releases/tag/v0.18.0):

> Improved range formater
> @josephfrazier brought his work on prettier's range formater here. Our range formater is now improved working.
> ⚠️ With eslint's integration it will format the entire document. But it still is waaaaaaaay better than before !