# VS Code Format Selection is formatting the entire document. Why?

Tags: visual-studio-code, format

I am simply trying to format only the selected text in my Vue project. I have prettier installed and can format the entire document just fine.

I need to format only the selected text which works on my home computer but not my work laptop. I can even right-click the selected text, and see the option `Format Selection`. If I click it, it formats the entire document.

[image]

What is going on? Please help.

Comment: I'd propose to close this as a dup of the broader https://stackoverflow.com/q/72717501/11107541

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same problem as you and the issues seems to be that with prettier-eslint not supporting range formatting.

See more here: https://github.com/prettier/prettier-vscode/issues/137